# HTML attribute align="center" not working

Tags: html

**Why is the `align="center"` attribute not working?**

*why is `style="text-align: center"` not working either?*

```html
<u><span align="center">Why is this not in the center?</span></u>
<br/>
<span style="text-align: center;">This is not in the center either</span>
```

Comment: Center of what? All of those are `span` elements, which have `display: inline` by default. You probably want a `block` element so it is the full width of the available space. You should probably read up on the [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) to get a more fundamental understanding of how browsers render things.

Comment: spans are inline elements. you need a block element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `u` tag is inline element so it cannot align item to center. Instead you can make a `div` in `u` tag and it will align.

HTML:

```html
<div class="centered">
  <u><span align="center">Why is this not in the center?</span></u>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```